# GeckoDriver must be in executable path in online server(wayscript.com)

Tags: python-3.x

I am running my code on online server wayscript.com and I am constantly getting error geckodriver needs to be in path although I have set the path of geckodriver. W1hen I run my code on local machine, I don't get any error. I am getting it while running it on online server. I have tried many solutions but they are of no use. Please help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

WayScript provides exact selenium setup instructions in their [docs here](https://docs.wayscript.com/library/modules/python/python-code-snippets#using-selenium).

Here is the required code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(30)

browser.get('https://wayscript.com/')

ps = browser.page_source
print(ps)

browser.close()
```